# Show text for certain amount of time

Tags: jquery, html, anchor, fade

Quick and dirty example:

```
<a href="" class="test">save</a>

$(".test").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).html("saved");
 };
```

I want have a link with save, after you click it, it displays saved for half a second,after that it fades back to the text loaded from within the  (has to be stored in a var or something).

If someone could give me a quick example how to get the text(/store/delay) within a anchor i think i'm able myself to animate it with things like fading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
$(".test").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = this;
    var text = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("saved");
    setTimeout(function(){
        //fade back
        $(that).html(text);
    }, 1000);
 });
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MPCQs/

Comment: Thank you, youre awesome. I have one more question: how to handle css?
I've tried the same way like html but it doesn't work
var css = $(this).css();

Comment: Ah i fixed it:
var css = $(this).css("margin-right");$(that).css("margin-right",css);

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `setTimeout`, like this:

```
<a href="" class="test">save</a>

$(".test").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var previousText = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("saved");
    setTimeout(function() { $(this).html(previousText) }, 500);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test').click(function(e) {
    var link = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).html("saved");
    setTimeout(function() { $(link).fadeOut(1000) }, 500);
  });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vPeT3/

Answer (score 0):

You could store the previous data ($(this).html()), change the text and then use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to reset the text after a specified amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(".test").click(function(e){
    var $a = $(this);
    var txt = $a.html();
    $a.html("saved").fadeOut('slow', function () { $a.html(txt).fadeIn('fast'); });
    return false;
 })
```

You can specify any value in milliseconds instead of 'slow' or 'fast' in the fade methods.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kSB9M/